# How to use ros on arm?

Tags: ros, rosout

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I reference the Documentation and follow the instructions of GumROS , try to cross compile ROS for my board.But,when I move it to my board ,then set environment variables,and then type "roscore" , I got an error " ERROR: rosout is not built. Please run 'rosmake rosout' ".I'm sure that rosout is in the bin dir.How can I solve it? THX~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147671/how-to-use-ros-on-arm?/) by [SmallFat](https://answers.ros.org/users/14066/smallfat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The GumROS instructions are a little out of date. There are several sets of instructions you may want to try on the  Installation page. http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation

The most recently updated one appears to be the OpenEmbedded instructions. I suggest you try that out: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OpenEmbedded

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0